# ASP .Net web api does not render HTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have developed an API using asp .net web API and all the API works precisely as expected. But when I run the API only HTML code is displayed on the browser. I guess I have removed some packages or made some configuration-related changes that I don't recollect now.
Below is the screenshot I get after running the API from the visual studio.

[image]

Comment: What is the `content-type` header of the response? That is what the browser will use to determine what to do with it. You can see it if you open up your development console in the browser and inspect the request/response.

Comment: @Igor Thanks a lot. I have added content type as application/json in global.asax. After removing it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Removed `content-type='application/json'` from the global.asax file and it started working.